# Static variables in Monodroid

Tags: c#, static, xamarin.android

I'd like to know if it is safe to use static variables as a long term storage of business entities in a Mono for Android app.

For instance, if I have this class:

```
public class Test{
 public static int MyStaticVariable{get;set;}
}
```

and in my main activity I have this code

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
   ...
   if (Test.MyStaticVariable){
     Test.MyStaticVariable=666;
   }
}
```

can I always rely on `Test.MyStaticVariable==666` or will that value be eventually be reset by the OS when my app goes out of scope and RAM has to be recycled?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is scoped to your process, and will not survive a process restart (absent additional code on your part to save/restore the variable).

This is no different than Java. :-)

If you want to save/restore the value, you should subclass [Android.App.Application](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.Application) and override [Application.OnLowMemory()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Application.OnLowMemory) and/or [Application.OnTrimMemory()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Application.OnTrimMemory(System.Int32)) and save the value to persistent storage. You can then restore this value within [Application.OnCreate()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Application.OnCreate).

(There is no way I know of to actually know when the process will be killed -- `Application.OnTerminate()` is only for emulators -- but *hopefully* Android will call the `OnLowMemory()`/`OnTrimMemory()` methods before it kills the process...)